# Is there a functional way to set a boolean true and keep it true?

Tags: jquery

I have some code in jQuery where I loop over an array and compare html values. When the values match, I put a boolean to true, and make sure it stays true.

```
var inArray = false;
$.each($myArray, function (index, value) {
  inArray = inArray || value.html() === $draggable.html(); // Once it's true, it'll stay true
});
```

Is there a nice functional way of writing this without having to use the variable?

Comment: Just break out of the loop once a `true` value is hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grep:-

```
$.grep($myArray, function(n) {
    return n.html() === $draggable.html(); 
}).length > 0;
```

Comment: Good old grep. Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Break out of the loop once a `true` value is hit:

```
$.each($myArray, function (index, value) {
    inArray = inArray || value.html() === $draggable.html(); // Once it's true, it'll stay true
    return !inArray; //returning true goes to next iteration, returning false breaks out.
});
```

Comment: Breaking out of the loop does not give me a true or false value to work with. It just breaks out of the loop. I want to have a true or false value without using a variable state.

Comment: @JREN You can include your verification logic in a function and use it where you need it, but a variable is a thousand times better. If your concern is to avoid your variable being overwritten once it's setted, you can store it elsewhere, in localStorage, for example, so it'll be safe from accidental manipulation on other parts of your code.